# How to run a script inside gitlab ci docker executor?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to run a script inside the docker container.

I tried using `docker cp` but it does not work as there are no running containers. `docker container ls` is empty.

Locally I am able to `docker cp my-custom-image:my_script.py my_script.py`
so the problem is not with my docker image.

```
stage-name:
  image: "my-custom-image:0.1.0"
  stage: my-stage
  script:
    - python3 my_script.py
```

Comment: why there are no running containers ?

Comment: IDK maybe gitlab does something differently.

Comment: what do you get when running your docker in the executor?

Comment: When I do ls, I just get my repository, cloned. (not the image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution

In the dockerfile of `my-custom-image`, I added these lines

```
COPY ./my_script.py /usr/local/bin/my_script.py
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/my_script.py
```

I added python3 shebang in `my_script.py`

```sh
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Then I am able to execute the script in the CI

```
stage-name:
  image: "my-custom-image:0.1.0"
  stage: my-stage
  script:
    - my_script.py
```